# How to count tr elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>data</td>
     <td>data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='product_details'>
     <td>product details</td>
     <td>product details</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='product_details'>
     <td>product details</td>
     <td>product details</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to count table rows whose class is product_details. How I do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `length` property of jQuery [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vw2SX/)**

```
len = $('.product_details').length //will find any element with class product_details
```

If you have same class with elements other then tr then

```
len = $('tr.product_details').length  //will find only tr with class product_details
```

To find within table, using descendant selector, withing table.

```
len = $('table tr.product_details').length
```

It would be better if you assign id to table, lets say id is `table1`

```
len = $('#table1 tr.product_details').length
```

Comment: 0 down vote
 

$(".product_details").length will return number of elements which has product_details class.

Comment: There is no element with class product_details but I feel to be on safe side we would include tr in selector. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, on this page https://planning.cheshireeast.gov.uk/applicationdetails.aspx?pr=22/4407M I am trying to get the tr.AIMRow elements so I can interact with the table, or '#grdResults_tblData' and then use child elements, but I am getting length = 0, which is frustrating, as I know there is at least one of them.
This is in Console. Should I ask this as a question for extra help?

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = $("table tr.product_details").length;
alert(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".product_details").length
```

will return number of elements which has `product_details` class

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
$('table tr.product_details').length
```

or

```
$('table tr.product_details').size()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = $('table tr.product_details').length;
```